# form-group Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Fiz uma form com o Bootstrap, porém preciso posiciona-lo no meio da tela.
posicionei com `col-md-offset-?` na horizontal, mas preciso posiciona-lo verticalmente.

alguma forma no BootStrap ou devo fazer por conta própria em uma CSS diferenciado?

Comment: Intuitivamente, acredito que seja `row-md-offset-?` pois `col` = coluna e `row` = linha. Porém você deveria reproduzir um exemplo funcionando no seu problema no http://jsfiddle.net e postar aqui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem várias formas de centralizar horizontalmente e verticalmente. Você está falando de "offset" para centralizar horizontalmente utilizando o *grid system* do Bootstrap, então é melhor entender o conceito porque os números `col-md-?` podem variar:

### Conceito de offset

O GRID do Bootstrap por padrão tem **12 colunas**, veja essa imagem com linhas de **6 e 12 colunas**:

[image]

Logo, se você quiser centralizar a coluna `col-md-6` o *offset* deve ser de **"3"**, assim ficam 3 colunas para cada lado, totalizando em **12 colunas**, mais fácil ver a imagem a seguir:

[image]

### Alinhamento Vertical

Tem várias formas de fazer isso, como você não colocou código nenhum, fica difícil de ser específico, eis algumas soluções umas mais profissionais do que outras:

1. Coloque um DIV de *container* do seu `form` com o seguinte CSS:

   ```
   height: 300px; /* obrigatório para centralizar verticalmente */
   top:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   margin:auto;
   position:absolute
   ```
2. Adicione `margin-top:100px` ao seu *container* ou `form`, ajuste o valor de acordo com sua necessidade, mas lembrando esse é um falso centro vertical, quando na verdade você está empurrando o objeto para baixo, e se altura variar a distância sempre será a mesma.
3. Também existe o `vertical-align:middle`, porém funciona com `tables` apenas, talvez tenha alguma gambiarra por aqui.

Comment: fiz exatamente como explicou com o `col-md-?` para o alinhamento horizontal, porem estava pensando nessa mesma forma que você explicou na vertical, achei que houvesse alguma maneira no bootstrap, mas da mesma forma agradeço a ajuda.